# How to get all rows in two foreach?

Tags: c#

I don't know how to get the first rows of a first foreach run with the first rows of a second foreach.
The second rows of a first foreach run with the second rows of the second foreach.

Because I get all data into List<> and the foreach two list.

My code like:

```
for (int i = valuesFrom; i < valuesTo; i++)
{
    values = name + " " + i;
    lstAliasImage.Add(values);
}
for (int j = 0; j < lstImgAdded.Items.Count; j++)
{
    string imgPath = lstImgAdded.Items[j].Text;
    lstNameImage.Add(imgPath);
}

foreach (var alias in lstAliasImage)
{
    foreach (var items in lstNameImage)
    {
        txtUser.Text = alisa;
        Save(items + " " + txtUser.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm finding it very hard to understand what you mean. It would help if you'd give a [mcve] of what you're trying to do - ideally with an example which just prints out values to the console rather than dealing with images. Include the input data in the example, and the expected output vs actual output.

Comment: Are you sure the lists are of the same length?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek yes. Two source sample is same length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a good old `for` cycle:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstAliasImage.Count; i++) {
    txtUser.Text = listAliasImage.ElementAt(i);
    Save(lstNameImage.ElementAt(i) + " " + txtUser.Text);
}
```

Here I assumed that by `alisa` you meant `alias`. Also, I assumed that the element count is the same. If your type has an indexer defined, then you can use `[i]` instead of `ElementAt(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop will solve your problem;

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstAliasImage.Count; i++)
{
        txtUser.Text = lstAliasImage[i];
        Save(lstNameImage[i] + " " + txtUser.Text);
}
```

But it is better to solve this in a different way. As both Lists are related, you should create a struct, and store that in the list. At least to avoid errors if both lists are not the same length. Something like

```
public struct ImageStruct
{
    public String alias;
    public String name;
}

List<ImageStruct> images = new List<ImageStruct>();

for (int i = valuesFrom; i < valuesTo; i++)
{
    images.Add(new ImageStruct()
    {
        alias="alias " + i,
        name="name " + i
    });
}

foreach (var item in images)
{
    txtUser.Text = item.alias;
    Save(item.name + " " + item.alias);
}
```

I hope you get the idea (I did not test the above code).